# Markov inequality in real analysis and in probability

Tags: real-analysis, probability-theory, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral, lebesgue-measure

The following is the definition of Markov inequality in

1. probability:
   [image]
2. measure theory:
   [image]

If I want to relate both, according to the definition of expected value:

$$\mathbb{E}(|f|)=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} |f|g_X(x)dx$$

where $g_X(x)$ is the probability density function of $X$, can I define
$$d\mu(x)=g_X(x)dx$$ so, I can transfrom the Riemann integral to the Lebesgue integral as following:
$$\mathbb{E}(|f|)=\int_X |f|d\mu(x)$$

So, I construct the equivalence of the definition of Markov inequality of both definition.

Is my derivation correct and valid?

Comment: The two definitions are the same, upto the notational differences of analyst and probabalists. Just recall that $E[X] = \int X d \mathbb{P} $, and that $\mathbb{P}$ is a measure.

Comment: @GWilliams Are they really? one of them has absolute values while the other doesn't

Comment: @BCLC:  Yes, and (because of that), the first one is false (consider $\Bbb{E}(X)=0$), but the second one is not. I think/hope that the OP just forgot the assumption $X\geq 0$ or an absolute value sign.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As GWilliams and  PhoemueX said, this is the same inequality in different notation (thus, no proof of equivalence is needed), provided that the probabilistic version is corrected to 
$$
\mathbb{P}(|X|\ge a)\le \frac{\mathbb{E}(|X|)}{a}
$$

Of course, the absolute value may be dropped if $X\ge 0$ a.s.